# Sum multiple formulas using a single sum function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

is there a fast way to accomplish this without typing each term manually?
[image: this].

one way of doing so would be adding a column "D" that contained all the terms then applying the sum to that column. like this where D2 would be equal to (A2+B2/C2) and so on.

[image: img]

my question now becomes "is there a way to accomplish this without manual typing or using column D?"

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: It seems obvious what the new formula would be with an added row, but what would the formula be if you added a new column?

Comment: sorry, it seems that my question wasn't very clear. I didn't mean a new column of data I meant a column that contains the formula for each row. I edited my question to better explain what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7):

`=SUM(A2:A4+B2:B4/C2:C4)`

After typing it you need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of just ENTER.

[image]